# Switching between tabs not possible online

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I wrote a shiny app which works fine on my machine and on my server. Now I migrated the app to another virtual server (running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). I can access the virtual server via a GUI and when I run the app on that virtual server in Rstudio it works fine. When I access the app (running with free shinyserver) from the internet, I reach the application and can see the dashboard. It actually looks fine, all the links work and so on, but I cannot switch between dashboard tabs. When I click on a tab, the webpage changes from "webpage/" to "webpage/#tab-2470-2" (or some other number behind "#tab-") but nothing happens.

Since the R code and the shiny config on my server (where everything works) and the new virtual server is exactly the same, I presume that the virtual server is missing some packages. It's a fresh installation aside from R, Rstudio, shinyserver, the required dependencies and all updates. The problem is that I do not get any error messages (shiny log directory is empty), so I do not even know where to start troubleshooting.

So I am wondering if anyone experienced the same behaviour or has an idea what I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look the browser console for errors, could be diferent version of bootstrap or some javascript library. I had similar trouble in a project, where the position of the elements on browser were diferent in production and development server. The solution was to update packages related to shiny.

Comment: I should have checked with different browser... It does not work with Firefox, but it works just fine with Chromium. So you are probably right. I still don't know what is wrong with Firefox, but at least I have a starting point now. Thanks!